# Preventing .htacess redirect chains with URL appended by trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a question that I wondered whether someone could help me with.

I am looking to create a redirect rule with .htaccess which sends all the following versions of the webpage to a single destination URL in one step i.e. We cannot have redirect rules kick in one after the other.

Specifically

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

The issue I have is that all internal pages need to be appended with a trailing slash.

Currently I can only get this to work with the redirects chaining like such:

```
https://example.com/example
```

Will then go to:

```
https://www.example.com/example
```

Before finally going to:

```
https://www.example.com/example/
```

I had a developer put something together but this seemed to cause a loop:

```
// Don’t correct the path when it ends in a slash
example.com^\/(.*)\/$ to https://www.example.com/$1

// Add the slash if it doesn’t end with one
example.com^\/(.*)(?<!\/)$ to https://www.example.com/$1/
```

Im not a developer myself but was hoping someone could help me with the correct regex? I'd be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Pages without . and ev. /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Others
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```